# Why airmon-ng does not create a monitoring interface?

Tags: wifi, airmon-ng

I am running a Kali Linux in a virtualbox. I want to test the security of my
wifi router with `airmon-ng` etc.

When I run `airmon-ng start eth0` Kali should create an additional interface.
However it does not create that interface. Kali's `eth0` is brigded to the host's 
`wlan0` interface.

- **Why `airmon-ng` does not create the `mon0` interface?**

Thanks to @Jan here more information about the Kali and the host system. The host system is a Ubuntu 14.04.

**The host system**

```
> iwconfig

 wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"some ssid"  
           Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <some MAC>
           Bit Rate=78 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
           Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Power Management:on
           Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-34 dBm  
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:10   Missed beacon:0

 > sudo airmon-ng start wlan0

 Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
 If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
 a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

 PID    Name
 1098   avahi-daemon
 1102   avahi-daemon
 1118   NetworkManager
 1145   wpa_supplicant
 6002   dhclient
 Process with PID 6002 (dhclient) is running on interface wlan0

 Interface  Chipset     Driver

 wlan0      Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]
            (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

**On Kali@virtualbox**

```
> iwconfig

eth0 no wireless extensions

lo no wireless extensions


> airmon-ng start eth0

Interface Chipset Driver
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't use anymore airmon-ng to enable monitor mode because it stop the network-manager service.

I prefer :

```
ifconfig wlan0 down;
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor;
if config wlan0 up;
```

as it is say up try `iwconfig` to check wlan0 mode

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention your chipset, driver, kernel and airmon-ng version, which would have made it easier to help you.

Not all drivers create mon0 for monitor mode, some enable it on the original interface (wlan0 in your case). Run `airmon-ng check` to check the status.
To confirm that your card is in monitor mode, run the command `iwconfig`. You can then confirm the mode is “monitor” and the interface name.

You could also run `airmon-ng check kill`, which will cause all processes that use the interface to exit.

> For the mac80211 drivers, the monitor mode interface is typically “mon0”. For ieee80211 madwifi-ng drivers, it is typically “ath0”. For other drivers, the interface name may vary.

[Source](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=aireplay-ng)

To learn more about the difference of the drivers, read [here](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_drivers)

Comment: I added more information about the host and the virtualbox system. I can create a `mon0` on the host system - but not on the virtualbox.

Comment: @Philipp err... if I'm not mistaking, you can't use monitor mode in a virtualized environment

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation for Kali from Offensive Security states that you'll have to get a  USB adapter with the proper chipset to use WiFi in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, I will execute `airmon-ng check kill` before changing to monitor mode.

Just like below:

```
iwconfig wlan0
ifconfig wlan0 down
airmon-ng check kill
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to type:

```
sudo airmon-ng start mon0
```

noticing that the interface is mon0 that has been enabled monitor mode.

```
" wlan0      Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]              
(monitor mode enabled on mon0)"
```